# Although my research area in PhD includes many fields

Tags: grammar

"Although my research area in PhD includes many fields in the network security and management...."

In the previous sentence, I don't know how to express the idea that during his phd studying, he did some research and that included many fields.

Besides, I am not sure whether the area and fields go together or do we have to say like "area includes many fields"....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would express this idea as follows:

"Although my PhD research includes many fields within network security and network management..."

Although a PhD is a degree (noun), in this context it modifies research [area] and is probably most effective as an adjective.  I have never heard the idiom "in PhD." It sounds like a foreign language (non-English) construction.  "area" seemed redundant and I omitted it, but it can return without changing the grammar or meaning.

"Although my PhD research area includes many fields within network security and network management..."

A general research area contains many fields. Each of which contains many sub-fields.
What was the general area of research? Which fields? And which sub-fields were researched?

This is generally true of all PhD research so I would be interested in capturing what was exceptional about this research?  Was it unusually cross-discipline?  Was there an unusually large cross-section of sub-domains?

Since network security and network management are themselves "fields," if you mean many sub-fields then you need to specify that.  You could say "many sub-fields in network security and..." but I chose to use "many fields within" to express this idea.

"network security and management" is confusing as one specific tech field and one general business field. If that is what is intended, leave it as is. "network security" is more of a two word noun than an adjective-noun pair and you can't count on network being strong enough to modify both "security" and "management"   If it is two specific tech fields then they both need to be named in full as I have done "network security" and "network management"  I know it seems repetitive but clarity is improved.  Alternately, "security and management of networks" but since your goal is to convey many fields it makes more sense to say "many fields within [list]"